# Redshift subquery not accepted

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, bigdata

I'm trying to execute the following query against my dataset stored in Redshift:

```
SELECT v_users.user_id AS user_id,
   v_users.first_name AS first_name,
   v_users.email AS email,
   COALESCE(v_users.country, accounts.region) AS country_code,
   profiles.language AS language,
   v_users.mobilenum AS mobile_num,
   NULL as mobile_verification_date,
   COALESCE(v_users.registration_date, accounts.date_created) AS activation_date,
   EXISTS (SELECT 1
             FROM cds.user_session_201612 AS users_session,
                  cds.access_logs_summary_201612 AS access_logs_summary,
                  views_legacy AS views_legacy
            WHERE users_session.userid = v_users.user_id
               OR access_logs_summary.userid = v_users.user_id
               OR views_legacy.user_id = v_users.user_id) AS has_viewed,
   NULL as preferred_genre_1,
   NULL as preferred_genre_2,
   NULL as preferred_genre_3
FROM users AS v_users,
     users_metadata AS v_users_metadata,
     account.account AS accounts,
     account.profile AS profiles
WHERE accounts.id = v_users.user_id
  AND profiles.id = v_users.user_id
  AND v_users_metadata.user_id = v_users.user_id
```

The problem which I get is the following:

```
ERROR:  This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error
```

which is caused by the subquery but how can I solve it? can you provide me some suggestions?

Comment: May I ask why you are using 4 cartesian products in your join statement?

Comment: @HaleemurAli can you elaborate it?

Comment: @HaleemurAli ok I got it what you mean. I'm using a 4 cartesian products because I need to retrieve data from those different tables

Comment: well actually i think it is wrong

Comment: @HaleemurAli it's now fixed

Comment: thanks, taking a crack at it.

Comment: Hey @Mazzy, could you please post an answer here of how you solved this? Would be helpful, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift doesn't allow correlated subqueries in the SELECT clause, which I don't think is a limitation as all the examples I've encountered can be otherwise expressed.

I've refactored the subquery as a CTE, and used a `left join` with an `is not null` to mark users who have or not viewed some thing.

This particular query below may not work, but any solution will likely take the following form:

```
WITH has_viewed AS (
  SELECT 
      u.user_id
  FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN cds.user_session_201612 AS users_session 
         ON users_session.userid = u.user_id
  LEFT JOIN cds.access_logs_summary_201612 AS access_logs_summary 
         ON access_logs_summary.userid = users.user_id
  LEFT JOIN views_legacy 
         ON views_legacy.user_id = v_users.user_id
  WHERE users_session.userid IS NOT NULL 
     OR access_logs_summary.userid IS NOT NULL 
     OR views_legacy.user_id
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT 
   v_users.user_id AS user_id
 , v_users.first_name AS first_name
 , v_users.email AS email
 , COALESCE(v_users.country, accounts.region) AS country_code
 , profiles.language AS language
 , v_users.mobilenum AS mobile_num
 , NULL as mobile_verification_date
 , COALESCE(v_users.registration_date, accounts.date_created) AS activation_date
 , has_viewed.user_id IS NOT NULL AS has_viewed
 , NULL as preferred_genre_1
 , NULL as preferred_genre_2
 , NULL as preferred_genre_3
FROM users AS v_users
JOIN users_metadata AS v_users_metadata 
  ON v_users_metadata.user_id = v_users.user_id
JOIN account.account AS accounts 
  ON accounts.id = v_users.user_id
JOIN account.profile AS profiles ON profiles.id = v_users.user_id
LEFT JOIN has_viewed 
       ON has_viewed.user_id = v_users.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all possible combinations,

1. `SELECT` subquery doesn't work
2. `CTE` (Common Table Expression) as shown by Haleemur Ali doesn't work either.

Now what I have tried - I needed an alternative to `GROUP BY`, as redshift doesn't accept `GROUP BY`. 
So I got this solution -

the `OVER` keyword.

SO as a replacement for `GROUP BY` I used `OVER` and `PARTITION BY` which goes like -

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (PARTITION BY **VARIOUS COLUMNS** ORDER BY datetime DESC) rn
    FROM schema.tableName
) derivedTable
WHERE derivedTable.rn = 1;
```

Maybe `OVER` might help you out. I am not sure though.